# Sql Express Connection in ASP

Tags: asp-classic, sql-server-express

I am trying to connect to sql express db and inserting record to one of the table inside it using following code.

```
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
    SQL_Conn_STRING = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=(local);Database=classic_asp_poc;uid=my-domain\username;pwd=my password"      
    conn.Open SQL_Conn_STRING
    Response.Write("con open")
```

I am getting error on open connection. Is there any problem in my connection string?

Comment: As @John has already answered SQL Server Express uses a `Named Instance` as the `Default Instance` is used by full editions of SQL Server and allows them to coexist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using mssql express, you need to add `\SQLEXPRESS` to your database address/ip, so in your example you would use `Server=(local\SQLEXPRESS)`

You're using an odbc connection string.  OLEDB or native client strings are the preferred method eg

```
SQL_Conn_STRING = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=local\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=classic_asp_poc;User Id=my-domain\username;Password=my password"
```

See this easy to remember link for more examples

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/